# Can't seem to center my h1?

Tags: html, css, center

I'm trying out some random stuff and seem to stumble upon a weird little annoyance. 
I cannot center my H1, I tried text-align on the content `div` and `h1` itself, no effect.

Can someone see the error I'm making? It must be something simple I'm overlooking.

Where is my hero ? :D

Here's is a link to my css/div, its an image.

[image]

It doesn't get centered in the middle exactly :(

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div id="content">
    <h1>Solid Design</h1>           
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
h1
{
    display: inline;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5em;   
}

#content 
{
    text-align: center;
}
#content p 
{
    width: 750px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, please reduce the code to a small example that reproduces the problem. No want wants to dig through that.

Comment: please post the relavant parts of your code here and not in an image. i.e. the html immediately around your h1 and the css that you are usingto style it.

Comment: You should try to reproduce the problem in JSFiddle. Then post the code and a link to the fiddle.

Comment: @arkascha the problem is only viable at 2 parts of the CSS, #CONTENT and H1 in HTML code it's the CONTENT part.

Comment: Better post your code in a JSfiddle and share the link here.http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Sorry, but I asked for a reduced example, not for some additional comment.

Comment: Hmm, what is JSfiddle, I opened that and its 4 text blocks, I paste my code in there? :D

Comment: @StefanoPeeters What IDE / Tool you are using ,I'm excited to see such a nice editor ! :)

Comment: My first guess is that you floated the logo/image on the left and then the test of the content is displaced accordingly.  Please post the code that includes the logo image and so on (HTML and CSS).

Comment: @dotNetSoldier It's [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com). I have the exact same theme as well :) It has a lot of emacs-like keyboard shortcuts and an ocean of plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the style `display:inline;` without a width style, this will make the element exactly the size that the text of the `h1` will take up.

To make the text center you need to give it a `width` and set `text-align` to `center`

```
h1 {
   display:inline;
   width:200px;
   text-align:center;
}
```

or take of the `display:inline` and just set `text-align:center`, as header elements are by default a block level element it will take up the full width it can.

```
h1 {
   text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: My suggested improvement `h1 {
   display:inline-block;
   width:200px;
   text-align:center;
}`

Answer (score 3):

I can see many answers have mentioned to give width. 
**NOTE**:- width and height property **DON'T** get applied if the display type is inline.
If display property is set to inline the width will be automatically set to width of content.
If you want the element to be inline and also specifically have some width or height then you should set display property to **inline-block**.

Detailed explanation https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the text inside H1 gets entangled with the element before it. Adding the top margin will free it.

```
h1 {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a width. This will work:

```
h1
{
    width:100%;
    display: inline;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5em;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove your `display:inline` from your css that you have applied to the h1 tag and then try to give it a `text-align` of center. If that doesn't work, please either -

1. Try to reproduce the issue on jsFiddle
2. Link us to your website.

Comment: Then you better link to your page, or create a link to jsFiddle, like the others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is from W3schools and it works in my Wordpress in html.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {text-align:center}
h2 {text-align:left}
h3 {text-align:right}
</style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read your code but check for floating elements around, they can cause problems. I actually was reading this for answers and epiphany struck, I hadn't {display:none}'d the mobile-nav hamburger icon, which caused my title to have a space at the side which I had not added. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

this one center my profile picture in my website...
this work for me with other modifications.

```
`top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
position: absolute;`
```

Comment: Needs explanation. As it is, this will center any div... but there are a lot of implications to absolute positioning. I feel this answer has a long way to go to address OP's question.